# Mongoose, Mongodb how to update multiple records in a document with deferent set of incoming values in single operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, if we have a Product variant scenario in which one product can have many variants. If we want to update the product and its variants, the request which comes from the client application is something like the below, and we don't know which one of the variants in the variants array has been changed by the client so we must update all the variants array in every request to update how to handle this kind of situation with "mongoose, MongoDB" update function or bulk write update operations?

Note: the product and variants are different documents and I want to update the variants in a single operation

```
{
   "_id": "5ef4f34dd43f52cff62459aa",
   "brand":"5cc9aeeaa3918f2e43e046af",
   "isActive":true,
   "name":"Product V",
   "supplier":"5ccb24fc3760713f4d9dbd1b",
   "supplierCode":"12343212234r2",
   "tags":[
      "5cd90de9f374d90ed569ab35"
   ],
   "type":"5ccad8a1efe8713bc1cac566",
   "variants":[
      {
         "_id":"5ef4fad0e0e5dfd29e188811",
         "retailMarkup":0,
         "retailPrice":0,
         "sku":"T001-W-M",
         "inventory":[
            {
               "storeId":"5ef4fad0e0e5dfd29e188823",
               "quantity":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "_id":"5ef4fad0e0e5dfd29e188811",
         "retailMarkup":0,
         "retailPrice":0,
         "sku":"T001-W-M",
         "inventory":[
            {
               "storeId":"5ef4fad0e0e5dfd29e188823",
               "quantity":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: is client sending full data back i.e. updated docs + non-updated docs?

Comment: yes they sending updated docs + non-updated

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the chat, this will suit your requirement

```
var bulk = db.variants.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.find( { _id: <variant_id_1> } ).update( { $set: <variant_doc_1>});

bulk.find( {_id: variant_id_2 } ).update( { $set: <variant_doc_2> } );
.....
bulk.execute();
```

Comment: on every request, there could be 100 variants or more what about the write operation performance?

Comment: @narmar sood also, there are many other variants and I want to update the specific product variants how do I declare to update the variant of this product with this ID

Comment: what I got from the question is that client is sending a single object with multiple variants that belongs to the same product

Comment: is this right or is there  something more to this question which I didn't get?

Comment: yes but how do you say only replace variants with these new variants came from the client with this product ID

Comment: can you please specify the database model of variants?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216820/discussion-between-namar-sood-and-user2620132).